# Floating left and parent height

Tags: html, css-float

This has probably been answered before, but I have spent some time looking and can't find an exact answer.

I have a parent div A that contains two divs B and C.

B and C are both floated left. C has no set height (grows w/ amount of text in it).

The problem: the parent A does not grow to the size of C. I know this has something to do with floating an element not being a part of the normal document flow, but I don't know how to fix it (setting a height on A doesn't help since it depends on the height of C).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add the property `overflow:hidden` to div A

Comment: It's good practice to avoid adding non-semantic divs whenever possible (as per second's suggestion below), so Catfish's overflow:hidden; suggestion is a better solution. More details and compatibility info at http://gtwebdev.com/workshop/floats/enclosing-floats.php

Comment: @peterjmag, If you want to open a dropdown div inside A, this solution will not work. But other solution will.

Answer (score 2):

a small div with clear:both after B and C (inside A) should do the trick